# Issues with Summernote in Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, summernote

I am unable to use summernote along with my vue js application. By Default, wysiwyg coming but its not binded with my variable. Please help !!

To display it , i am using

```
<div id="summernote"  name="editor" :model="form.trip_notes" v-on:change="value => { form.trip_notes = value }"></div>
```

While declaring

```
   data() {
       return {
           form: {
               trip_notes: null
                  }
              }
           }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with laravel nor summernote

Answer (score 0):

Use the `v-model` directive to bind your variables to form input elements.

`v-model="form.trip_notes"`

Learn more: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings